# modprobe: FATAL: Module cifs not found in directory (Wrong version)

Tags: virtual-machine, cifs

Running Ubuntu 22 in a Windows VM. Trying to give it access to a shared folder on my windows drive.

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user '//ip/folder' /folder_on_ubuntu
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
```

Found [modprobe: FATAL: Module cifs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613472/modprobe-fatal-module-cifs-not-found-in-directory-lib-modules-4-4-0-19041-mic) but I am not using a Windows Subsystem for Linux, I'm in a VM.

```
zgrep -i cifs /proc/config.fz
gzip: /proc/config.fz.gz: No such file or directory

modprobe cifs
modprobe: FATAL: Module cifs not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.0-1016-azure
```

Clearly the module is missing.

```
find / -name "cifs"
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-88-generic/kernel/fs/cifs
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-1005-azure/kernel/fs/cifs
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-27-generic/kernel/fs/cifs
And a bunch of /usr/src/linux... folders
```

Ah, it's a version difference? Maybe updating it will solve it.

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
cifs-utils is already the newest version (2:6.14-1ubuntu0.1).
```

Guess not. I tried the classic uninstall and reinstall, but noticed with

```
find / -name "cifs"
```

It presented me with the same output as before.

I apologize if this is a stupid question, I am fairly new to Linux, but I am at a roadblock and have no idea how to continue. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `/lib/modules/6.2.0-1016-azure` - this doesn't look like a normal Ubuntu distro. Maybe you could use one.

Comment: We see four different kernel versions in your post. which one of these are you actually running (`uname -r`)?

Comment: It should be `find / -name 'cifs.ko*'` to find the relevant kernel modules. Other regex options available...

Comment: @MarcusMüller 6.2.0-1016-azure

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the 6.2.0-1016-azure image currently does not support cifs by default as of the latest update, 1015 worked fine.

I did however find the answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1410701/linux-image-6-2-0-1016-azure-cifs-is-not-supported) and will post it below.

> Functional workaround found in a different discussion.
>
> The current workaround answer for new (i.e. no rollback kernel option)
> systems is to:
>
> ```
> apt install -y linux-modules-extra-azure
> ```
>
> Apparently the problem
> is that they moved the location of the CIFS driver from `fs/cifs/` to
> `fs/smb/client/`, but didn't update the include file for building the
> base modules package to include the new path.
>
> https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg514627.html

**Note**: Should you forget to reinstall `cifs-utils`, you will likely get [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113874/mount-t-cifs-results-in-cannot-mount-readonly-error?noredirect=1) lovely 'read only' error.

Comment: you're not dumb! Such things happen.